# How to use a WITH block with dynamic sql query

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, common-table-expression, dynamic-sql

I've got a `plpgsql` function that needs to prepare data from 3 tables based on user input, and export the data using `COPY TO`. The data are road accidents, so the 3 tables are `accident`, `casualty` and `vehicle`, each accident links to zero or more records in the vehicle and casualty tables via an `accidentid` column that exists in all three tables. `severity` and `local_authorities` are input parameters (both `text []`).

```
sql_query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM accident WHERE severity = ANY(' || quote_literal(severity)
 || ') AND local_auth = ANY (' || quote_literal(local_authorities) || ')';

EXECUTE sql_query INTO result_count;

IF result_count > 0 THEN
   -- replace Select Count(*) With Select *
   sql_query = Overlay(sql_query placing '*' from 8 for 8);
   
   -- copy the accident data first
   EXECUTE 'COPY (' || sql_query || ') TO ' || quote_literal(file_path || file_name_a) ||
     ' CSV';
```

This first bit will get the relevant accidents, so I'm now looking for the most efficient way to use the accidentid's from the first query to download the related vehicle and casualty data.

I thought I'd be able to use a `WITH` block like this:

```
-- replace * with accidentid
sql_query = Overlay(sql_query placing 'accidentid' from 8 for 1);

WITH acc_ids AS (sql_query)
  EXECUTE 'COPY (SELECT * FROM vehicle WHERE accidentid IN (SELECT accidentid FROM
  acc_ids)) TO ' || out_path_and_vfilename || ' CSV';
  EXECUTE 'COPY (SELECT * FROM casualty WHERE accidentid IN (SELECT accidentid FROM
  acc_ids)) TO ' || out_path_and_cfilename || ' CSV';
```

but get an error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
>
> LINE 1: WITH acc_ids AS ( $1 ) EXECUTE 'COPY (SELECT * FROM accident....

I have tried the above in a non-dynamic test case e.g.

```
WITH acc_ids AS (
    SELECT accidentid FROM accident
    WHERE severity = ANY ('{3,2}')
    AND local_auth = ANY ('{E09000001,E09000002}')
    ) 
    SELECT * FROM vehicle
    WHERE accidentid IN (
    SELECT accidentid FROM acc_ids);
```

which works. Unfortunately the server is still running `Postgres 8.4` so I can't use `format()` for the time being.

Perhaps this isn't possible with a `WITH` block, but I hope it at least illustrates what I'm trying to achieve.

**Edit/Update**

The main goal is to get the relevant data from the 3 tables in 3 separate `csv` files, ideally without having to run the selection on the `accident` table 3 times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run a query (part) that is stored in a string variable, you need a dynamic query like

```
EXECUTE 'WITH acc_ids AS (' || sql_query || ')'
   'SELECT ... ';
```

Either the whole query is a string executed by `EXECUTE`, or the whole query is static SQL. You cannot mix them.

Do you need a CTE? If you can express the query as a join, the optimizer has more options.

Comment: having the whole query as a string makes sense, I was thinking that may be the issue. Don't think I can do this with a join since I need 3 separate export files, otherwise I'll have to rewrite the whole import routine on the other side of this

Comment: actually your suggestion above won't work since my statement after `with acc_ids as` is `copy (select...` not just `select`. Given that the file name and path for the `copy` statement are also held in variables I'd almost need a nested `execute 'copy (select` within the first `execute` string, which is looking impractical with all the quoting going on

Comment: What's the problem with writing something like `COPY (WITH ... SELECT ...) TO ...`?

Comment: no problem...I haven't phrased my question very well. You answer the question I asked though, so I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

This does what I need to do without CTE but I can't see this being the most efficient way of solving this since I have to perform the same query on the `accident` table 3 times:

```
sql_query = sql_query || which_tab || ' WHERE severity = ANY ('||
   quote_literal(severity) ||') AND ' || date_start || ' AND ' ||
   date_end || ' AND local_auth = ANY (' ||
   quote_literal(local_authorities) || ')';

-- replace * with COUNT(*)
sql_query = Overlay(sql_query placing 'COUNT(*)' from 8 for 1);
EXECUTE sql_query INTO result_count;

IF result_count > 0 THEN

   -- replace COUNT(*) with *
   sql_query = Overlay(sql_query placing '*' from 8 for 8);
   -- copy the accident data first
   EXECUTE 'COPY (' || sql_query || ') TO ' || quote_literal(file_path ||
      file_name_a) || ' CSV';

   sql_query = Overlay(sql_query placing 'accidentid' from 8 for 1);
   -- vehicles
   EXECUTE 'COPY (SELECT * FROM vehicle WHERE accidentid IN (
    SELECT accidentid FROM accident
    WHERE severity = ANY (' || quote_literal(severity) || ')
    AND local_auth = ANY (' || quote_literal(local_authorities) ||')))
    TO ' || quote_literal(file_path || file_name_v) || ' CSV';
   -- casualties
   EXECUTE 'COPY (SELECT * FROM casualty WHERE accidentid IN (
    SELECT accidentid FROM accident
    WHERE severity = ANY (' || quote_literal(severity) || ')
    AND local_auth = ANY (' || quote_literal(local_authorities) ||')))
    TO ' || quote_literal(file_path || file_name_c) || ' CSV';
END IF;
```